# Is there a way to search in a specific file using Azure Cognitive Search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to use Azure Cognitive Search to search csv content stored in Azure blob. The problem is that I have multiple files in the blob. For example, I have file a, b, c, d and etc. Is there a way to search only in file a? I'm thinking about adding one more column in my csv file to store the file name. But I'd like to know if there is an easy way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The blob indexer can automatically pull certain metadata about your file and include them in your Azure Search document (including the file name), as long as those fields are included in your index definition
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#indexing-blob-metadata

If you make those fields filterable, you'll be able to emit a search query with a filter to only include the desired file(s).